# How to edit php file and return wordpress blog entries in multiple columns?

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress

I am using the same theme as this site http://foreignpolicydesign.com/v3/.  However, my test site does not distribute the blog entries in columns

What might be causing this problem?  I am suspecting it is whatever sets the $col_class to set the x1 ~ xN, but I cannot find the source of this variable.

Here is the code:

```
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/tanzaheader.php');

        // [grid column setting]
        $col_w = 200; // width of grid column
        $gap_w = 35;  // padding + margin-right (15+15+5)
        $max_col = 5; // max column size (style div.x1 ~ xN)

        // * additional info *
        // check also "style.css" and "header.php" if you change $col_w and $gap_w.
        // - style.css:
        //   div.x1 ~ xN
        //   div.grid-item
        //   div.single-item
        //   ... and maybe #sidebar2 li.widget.
        // - header.php:
        //   gridDefWidth in javascript code.
        //
        // if you want to show small images in main page always, set $max_col = 1.

        // [grid image link setting]
        $flg_img_forcelink = true;   // add/overwrite a link which links to a single post (permalink).
        $flg_img_extract = false;    // in single post page, extract thumbnail link to an original image.
        $flg_obj_fit = 'large-fit';  // none | small-fit | large-fit ... how to fit size of object tag.

        // * additional info *
        // if you use image popup utility (like Lightbox) on main index, set $flg_img_forcelink = false;
?>      

<!--  <?php if (is_singular()) : $is_top_single = true; /* wide column for single post */ ?>  -->


<?php /* make a new query for grid items (in single page) */
        $new_query_arg = 'paged='.$paged;

        // use this code if you want filter items by category.
        $arr_catID = array(20);
        foreach( get_the_category() as $cat) $arr_catID[] = $cat->cat_ID;
        if ( count($arr_catID) ) $new_query_arg .= '&cat=' . join(',', $arr_catID);

        query_posts($new_query_arg);
?>

<!--  <?php endif; /* end of if is_singular() */ ?>  -->

        <div id="grid-wrapper">

<?php if (have_posts()) :
        if ( $is_top_single ) $GLOBALS['more'] = false; //important
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
        $content = get_the_content('Details &raquo;');
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
        list($col_class, $grid_img) = adjust_grid_image(
                $content,
                $col_w,
                $gap_w,
                $max_col,
                $flg_img_forcelink,
                $flg_obj_fit
        );
?>
                <div <?php post_class('grid-item ' . $col_class); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                        <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <?php if ($grid_img) echo '<div class="grid-image">' . $grid_img . '</div>'; ?>
                        <div class="post-body">
<?php
        $content = preg_replace('/<img(?:[^>]+?)>/', '', $content); // remove img tags
        $content = preg_replace('/<a([^>]+?)><\/a>/', '', $content); // remove empty a tags
        $content = preg_replace('/<p([^>]*?)><\/p>/', '', $content); // remove empty p tags
        $content = preg_replace('/<object(.+?)<\/object>/', '', $content); // remove object tags
        echo $content;
?>
                        </div>
                        <p class="post-meta">
                        Published on <?php the_time( get_option('date_format') ); ?> <?php the_time(); ?>.<br />
                        Filed under: <?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', '); ?>
                        <?php edit_post_link(__("Edit This"), '(', ')'); ?><br />
                        <?php /*comments_popup_link();*/ ?>
                        </p>
                </div>

<?php endwhile; else : ?>

                <div class="grid-item x1">
                        <h2>Not Found</h2>
                        <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
                </div>

<?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- /grid-wrapper -->

        <div class="pagination" id="grid-pagination">
          <?php paginate_links2($is_top_single); ?>
        </div>

<?php /* reset the query */
        wp_reset_query();
?>

</div><!-- /container -->

<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/tanzafooter.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns are not created by PHP code, they are created dynamically by a jQuery plugin.

Your theme is referencing it here:

`http://wpbeta.nfshost.com/wp-content/themes/js/jquery.vgrid.0.1.4-mod.js`

But that returns a 404 file not found error.